# Permanent socket.io server on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, websocket, socket.io

I'm starting a socket.io server by entering a command:

```
node server.js
```

But that sometimes stops, or I need to have a terminal window open for it to run.

How can I set this up on a Linux server (Ubuntu) so there is a permanent server running in the system (like Apache) and if it stops it restarts automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2)

after install the npm package you can use pm2 command line :

```
pm2 start server.js
```

You can use too [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) or [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) to detect when your server files changed. It will restart automatically your server and you don't need anymore to stop / start your node application.

***Note than pm2 is used for production and nodemon for development***

Comment: I wanted to use pm2, but it doesn't work with my node version. I've used forever, and it seems to be working well so far. Many thanks.

Comment: Glad to help you PJ_

Answer (score 0):

You can also use tmux (no need for any installations) by writing the following in the command line:

```
tmux
cd /path/to/application
node server.js
```

To exit the session while keeping the application running use:

```
Ctrl+b
d
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use upstarter and turn your node application into an ubuntu service. That's the thing I use in production.

- To install:

  ```
  npm install -g upstarter
  ```
- To use:

  ```
  sudo upstarter
  ```

And the remainder is just user prompts. In order to start/stop/restart your upstarter-generated service:

```
sudo start/stop/restart <name-of-the-service>
```

Upstarter also has this one big advantage over PM2/Forever: It can be used with non-node applications.